# How to retain an object with code block? Or: How to lay out async operations correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks

First of all my task is to download something via a socket with HTTP protocol. For that I chose to open a socket connection with GCDAsyncSocket which works fine. Also the http-protocol implementation works fine.

The class is structured basically like this:

```
//REQUEST OBJECT
@implementation HttpRequest{
//completion and fail block which will be called to the receiver
   void (^_failBlock)();
   void (^_completionBlock)();
}



-(void)performRequest:completionBlock andFailBlock:failBlock{
    //assigning blocks for later use
    _completionBlock = completionBlock;
    _failBlock = failBlock;
   //start the request
}

-(void)receiveAsyncSocketCallback{
 //receive the answer and parse it
 // if the request is complete call completionBlock or failBlock
}
```

My problem is that my request object gets deallocated instantly after I start the request like this (and not holding a strong reference to it):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    HttpRequest* request =  [[HttpRequest alloc] init];

    [request performUrlRequest:@"https://someurl.com/someFile"
              completionBlock:^(int statusCode, NSDictionary *httpHeader, NSData *body) {

            //Do something with the retrieved data

          }
                failBlock:^(int statusCode, NSDictionary *httpHeader, NSData *body) {

            //connection failed for some reason

                }];


}
```

What I understand is that no object is retaining my request object because I don't hold a strong reference from any other object on it. Okay.

But my previous understanding was that when I implement a code block in another object which is still alive this will retain my request object until the code block is called. And I have done this in other projects where it worked exactly like that but I cannot spot the difference.

To avoid the deallocation of the object I could assign it to some ivar in the object where I created it and where I need the response of that request. But I don't like to hold those references because it feels kind of senseless so I choose to let the object retain itself with

```
__strong HttpRequest *_retained_self;
```

which I also don't like because of potential memory leaks. I feel like I am missing a good architecture here.

Can someone give me a proposal for how to lay out that correctly?

Comment: Did you try creating a `HttpRequest` variable in your interface?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what u exactly mean

Comment: Is this code inside of a Class / ViewController?

Comment: yes, i updated the code so u see the rough structure of the request itself

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing `request` inside of the two blocks, you are fine when you **copy** the block. The runtime will than keep strong references to the object. The easiest way to do this is to use properties with type `copy` for the blocks. Strong references to the blocks are not enough.

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^failBlock)();
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^completionBlock)();
```

Comment: I've added property declarations. Assigning a block will copy them and keep strong references to the objects used inside.

Comment: you mean in the view controller where I start the request? If I copy the blocks there I could as well hold a reference to the request itself...

Comment: Yes, the necessary operation is to copy the block as I mentioned in my post. You can do that explicitly by calling `copy`, or implicitly by assigning to a property with `copy` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Make them as properties with (copy) and then implement dealloc method where you set them nil to avoid memory leaks.